# use dialogFlow custom payload to send image in whatsapp

Tags: dialogflow-es, whatsapp

Good evening!

Everything is configured with whatsapp.
I use auto reply app and dialogFlow to make a little robot that automatically responds to certain things already ordered on whatsapp. The problem is that I can only use text as an answer; I would like from dialogFlow to respond with an image. Maybe should I use custom payload?